# Как импортировать методы js модуля в react ts

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

Я пытаюсь импортировать методы js модуля в мой tsx компонент вот таким образом:

```
import { scanner_connect, start_scan_btn, stop_scan_btn, select_finger } from 'webscan-lib/wserver.js'
```

Но это приводит к ошибке:

> TS7016: Could not find a declaration file for module
> 'webscan-lib/wserver.js'.
> 'D:/Рабочая/react/new-ds45/node_modules/webscan-lib/wserver.js'
> implicitly has an 'any' type.   Try `npm i --save-dev @types/webscan-lib` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file
> containing `declare module 'webscan-lib/wserver.js';`

В tsconfig.json установлено "allowJs": true.

Что я делаю не так?

Comment: Эм, а вы сообщение-то прочитали?

Comment: Прошу прощения за невнимательность, все заработало.